# Magento custom admin module - use template instead of grid?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create a custom admin module and I want to use a template file instead of using a grid. Can someone give me an example of how I would do this. Not sure if it is possible to do this in the controller or if I still need a block and then reference the template there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **ModuleCreator** patterns we all have made Admin modules with grids, forms, etc... but, at the end, admin environment is like the frontend

Asuming you are familiar with grid block structure & classical Admin modules. You have a controller, which usually calls something like

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

Then, you define in your layout something like

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="yourmodule/adminhtml_yourmodule" name="yourmodule" />
</reference>
```

Where your grid should load, etc...

You only need to extend **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template** block in your block `yourmodule/adminhtml_yourmodule` instead of extending any widget class (as they load their own templates), and then assign a template (in the block constructor, or in the layout, as you preffer)

**Examples**

Define template in block constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('xxx/xxxx.phtml');
}
```

Define template in layout

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="yourmodule/adminhtml_yourmodule" name="yourmodule" template="xxx/xxx.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

As you are extending **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template** you'd place your template into `app/design/adminhtml/XX/XX/template` folder